# The Alexander polynomial of the theta graph

Tags: graph-theory, knot-theory

I am trying to figure out Alexander polynomials, so I am trying to calculate some that look simple. I started with the theta graph

[image]

which has presentation

$$\langle a,b,c|c=ab\rangle$$

I have calculated the derivatives and got the matrix:

$$\left( -1 \quad -t \quad 1 \right)$$

So the polynomial should be $-t$ correct?

Comment: How do you define the Alexander polynomial of a graph?

Comment: For a one-variable Alexander polynomial, you need a choice of homomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}$.  Oriented knots and links come with such a homomorphism by Alexander duality (i.e., the existence of oriented meridians), but for graphs you need to generalize the notion of an orientation to an element of $H_1(G)$.  There's also a notion of a multivariable polynomial with one variable per generator of $H_1(G)$.